# jsfiddle not showing any output when i want to show array results from model to view?

Tags: knockout.js, jsfiddle

This is js fiddle:
[fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/30493/)

```
var CITIES = ko.observableArray([]);
ko.applyBindings(CITIES, document.getElementById("popupCityList"));
var arr = [];
arr.push({ "cityname": "Mumbai", "cityid": 1 });
```

I am pushing object to observable array. But i am not able to see any result. I am very new to knockout. Can anyone please help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things going wrong here:

- Javascript is case sensitive: when your property is named `cityname`, you cannot refer to it using `CityName`
- Your viewmodel is an observable array, which does not have a `CITIES` property. Refer to the data inside the viewmodel with `$data` (`foreach: $data`), or wrap your array in an object (`ko.applyBindings({CITIES: CITIES})`)
- You shouldn't make custom attributes without prefixing them with `data-`

A corrected version:

```js
var CITIES = ko.observableArray([]);

var viewmodel = {
  CITIES: CITIES
};

ko.applyBindings(viewmodel, document.getElementById("popupCityList"));

var arr = [];

arr.push({
  "cityname": "Mumbai",
  "cityid": 1
});

CITIES(arr);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div>
  <ul id="popupCityList" data-bind="foreach: CITIES">
    <li data-bind="text: cityname"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**Additional notes:**

- You can push directly to an observable array. I.e.: you don't need the `arr` but can write `viewmodel.CITIES.push({ /* ... */ })`
- It's a good idea to follow some code conventions regarding the casing of your variable names.

Comment: you have not binded the cityid and cityname attribute with each li.

Comment: I removed them because they do not produce valid html: https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#global-attributes They'd work though, if you make the property names lowercase like your city data. I'd advice to rename them to `data-cityid` and `data-cityname` though. I.e.: `attr: {'data-cityid': cityid, 'data-cityname': cityname}`.

Comment: Can you please edit this fiddle:- https://jsfiddle.net/8d1ut6u0/9/ to add these data attributes. When i add them, i see no output. I think i am not doing it correctly- there is some syntax error.

Comment: Here's my suggestion (literally) copy-pasted int your fiddle... https://jsfiddle.net/a68w6npc/

Comment: Great! thank a lot! there was some syntax error in my version.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var CITIES = ko.observableArray([]);
// You are giving the wrong element
ko.applyBindings(CITIES, document.getElementById("popupCityList")[0]);
var arr = [];
CITIES.push({ "cityname": "Mumbai", "cityid": 1 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.1.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<select id="popupCityList" data-bind="options: CITIES,
                                      optionsText: 'cityname',
                                      value: 'cityid',
                                      optionsCaption: 'Choose...'"></select>
```